# ArcGIS query "dash" character multiple times in a string & replace/remove dash

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, query, string

Using ArcMap 10.2.2 and have a string field in an attribute table that has values such as:

xxxx-xxxx-x
xxxx-xxxx-x
xxxx-xxxx-x
xxxx-xxxx
xxxx-xxxx
xxxx-xxxx

1. I want to query for all records that have two dashes in a string (three records in the sample above).
2. I want to remove the second dash from the string.

I would prefer to do this in two separate steps where I can first query/identify identify the records w/two dashes and then run an update to remove the second dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use Select by Attributes:

```sql
"stringfield" LIKE '%-_'
```

This will select any record where the value in your field has a dash as the second-to-last character.

[image]

[image]

Then use the Field Calculator to remove the second dash -> Python Parser, Show Codeblock.

In Pre-logic script code:

```py
def removedash(field):
    if field[-2] == '-':
        x = "{0}{1}".format(field[:-2], field[-1:])
        return x
    else:
        return field
```

Expression:

```
removedash(!stringfield!)
```

Where `stringfield` is the name of the field you're wanting to update.

[image]

[image]